# Slick Slider single row with auto width

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Basically we need to create a carousel that has a default of 9 slidesToShow and 9 slidesToScroll. This is simple, but our carousel is being replicated across multiple pages and some pages may only have 2-3 slides (we're using it to show categories and child categories).

At the moment our carousel works fine for pages that have 9 categories/slides or more. But fails when it hits less than that, it then creates multiple rows of single items.

Can slick auto-width the carousel items so they always fit in one row and fill the space? For example, this is our default;

```
< [_] [_] [_] [_] [_] [_] [_] [_] >
```

But this happens when there is less than 9 (example 3);

```
[_______________________________]
[_______________________________]
[_______________________________]
```

What we'd like to happen is (example 3);

```
[_________][_________][_________]
```

We've tried all of the current options in the docs.

```
slickOptions: {
        slidesToShow: 9,
        slidesToScroll: 9,
        rows: 1,
        swipeToSlide: true,
        infinite: true,
        variableWidth: true,
      }
```

Comment: Maybe you can dynamically set the `slidesToShow` and `slidesToScroll` based on the number of slides. It might help to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Count the slides and use them to set Slick. `slidesToShow: $(.slide').length,` .